# NullPointerException Issue with view

Tags: android, view, timer, nullpointerexception

I think there is something that I'm just not yet getting about how these Views are to be coded. This is the third time I have had to come and post a question rearding them in the last 3 days! :S

Anyway, my problem is as follows.

*edit:*
This *is the code inside a* method *that* gets executed on a button press:
(Points of importance are noted)

```
>>  setContentView(R.layout.stop);
>>  timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2);
    GPSMain.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);

    startService(new Intent(context, Timer.class));

}
```

This is the Timer class that is executed in the "startService" call:
(Again points of importance are noted)

```
public class Timer extends Service {

static int totalSeconds = 0;
private int hour = 0;
private int min = 0;
private int sec = 0;
String mTimeFormat = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
final private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
static String timeTaken;
Context context = this;

Runnable mUpdateTime = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { updateTimeView(); }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Timer Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);
}

public void updateTimeView() {
    totalSeconds += 1;
    sec += 1;
    if(sec >= 60) {
        sec = 0;
        min += 1;
        if (min >= 60) {
            min = 0;
            hour += 1;
        }
    }
>>  timeTaken = String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec);
>>  GPSMain.timer.setText("Time Taken: "+timeTaken);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTime, 1000);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

The logcat returns a NullPointerException on the following line of code:

```
GPSMain.timer.setText("Time Taken: "+timeTaken);
```

If I remove that line of code the code executes properly*, well I say properly because it executes all the way to the end of the application code, but the reason that I want to print the timer to the screen as it is counting is because I need to make sure that it is functioning correctly.

*not only does it run properly but it displays the timer text view with it's default defined string from the xml. It's only when I try to update it from the java that it crashes.

Here is the full xml file that the code is referencing at this point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopbutton"
    android:layout_width="100px" 
    android:layout_height="100px" 
    android:text="Stop"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
/>
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/timer2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Time Taken:       unknown"
    android:layout_below="@+id/timer"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE!

The MyTimer Class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class MyTimer extends AsyncTask { 

Timer _timerTask = new Timer();
static int totalSeconds = 0, hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0;
static String mTimeFormat = "%02d:%02d:%02d";
static String timeTakenString;

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

        TimerTask timer = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                totalSeconds += 1;
                sec += 1;
                if(sec >= 60) {
                    sec = 0;
                    min += 1;
                    if (min >= 60) {
                        min = 0;
                        hour += 1;
                    }
                }
                timeTakenString = String.format(mTimeFormat, hour, min, sec);
                GPSMain.timer.setText("Time Taken: "+GPSMain.timeTaken);

            }
        };
         (_timerTask).scheduleAtFixedRate(timer,1000,1000);

    return null;
}

}
```

The method to start the timer thread:

```
void startService(){

    setContentView(R.layout.stop);

    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2);

    GPSMain.button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);

    new MyTimer().execute();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TimerTask instead of Service . Here is the code ..

```
TimerTask timer = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                        // Here you can update your UI
    }
 }

Timer _timerTask = new Timer();
        _timerTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer,60000,60000);
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try inpliment your code:

The method scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, int, int) is undefined for the type Timer

eclipse gives me these tips:
1. Create method scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask, int, int)

or

2. Add cast to _timerTask

Comment: not yet, the app tuns to the end but I dont think the AsyncTask is getting executed... Posing uo the code now

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a `Service` here? Why don't you just use `AsyncTask`? A Service is usually used when you need to run something in background, with no layout shown to user. Your application shows data to user, so the best way for you to solve your problem is to run a separate thread, not a service. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I never thought of doing that. I'm not very good with threads to be honest so maybe that's why. I'll look into it tho and if that solves my problem then I'll accept your answer :) Thanks for yout help!!

Comment: You're welcome! You should take a look at AsyncTask class, it provides a very simple access to multithreading and helps you synchronize with your UI thread to redraw the views. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! looking at it now, going to try see if I can impliment it with the code posted below :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, I seriously don't know much about services, but in all cases, you should be accessing UI only from the UI thread.

I your case, I feel the Activity that has the button and the Service are two different classes, with the service not possessing any object of the activity. I think the way you're setting the text view from a service may be an issue. but again, i don't know much about services.

On the other note, I agree with Egor, unless you have a lot of activities and each keeps doing a lot of network activity, AsyncTask is the way to go.

Comment: yeah I am trying to get that implimented at the moment, but I dont think it is executing, posting the code in my main question now

Comment: `doInBackground()` doesn't run in the UI thread, it a background worker thread, thus you can't access the TextView from it or from any child thread started out of it. AsyncTask has the method `onPostExecute()` to do stuff on the UI. This sample code may help you with AsyncTask: https://github.com/Sheikh-Aman/Android_Samples/tree/master/5.%20NetworkOperationDemo

Comment: ah thanks! I didnt know that! This is a really great site for novice programmers! :)